# Pass an Array of known shape but unknown size to component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript. Currently, I am trying to pass a prop with the name `items` to a React component.

`items` is of unknown length but of known shape:

```
items = [
    [string, (unknown) => unknown],
    [string, (unknown) => unknown],
    [string, (unknown) => unknown],
    ...
]
```

The component is a simple accordion component that should be reusable. The fist element in every array describes the titles that should be rendered and the function describes an action that should be triggered on click. Since this is a reusable component, the component should accept any action with arbitrary arguments and return values.

This is pretty straight forward in JS but I cant wrap my head around how to specify the types in TS? Can someone help or point me in the right direction?

**Update for future reference:**
This solution does the job.
-1 : define items as an Array of touples.
-2 : defining the inner array as a touple (array with fixed number of elements.
-3 : defining the function as containing an arbitrary number of arguments and returning `<any>` value.

```
interface Props {
    title: string,
    items: Array<[string, (...args: any) => any]>,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your shape as a type:

```js
type Type = [string, (arg0: any) => any];
let items: Array<Type> = [];
```